# Can I use fast tremolo or triads on the third register?

Tags: composition

When I compose music I always tend to avoid writing fast tremolo and chords in the low register as it can get really muddy, but where is the boundary after which I should avoid tremolos and chords?

Can I actually play fast in the third register (A3 to G3) or will it get too muddy?

I think the third register is ok to do this, but my ear is untrained and I can't know for sure if there is something wrong with doing this.

**Edit**:
There is a comment in which it is asked about what instrument I am referring to, the comment has a lot of upvotes so I am assuming that the choice of instrument plays a role.

So with this in mind, first of all the instruments I am most interested to know about are strings and trombones, but I would also like to ask why does this depend on the instrument, is it because some instruments have more overtones than others hence they tend to sound muddier?

**Edit 2**: To be more specific, I am interested in using a tremolo for cellos on third register in the context of a full orchestra (more strings focused with the rest of the orchestra either accenting or playing sustained chords) and also I am interested on wether I can play chords on trompones on the third register for a full orchestra (not on the same section).

Comment: I think this question is a bit too vague to answer. Assuming that you are asking two things - what the lower bound of the register for playing tremolos is, and what the lower bound of the register for playing triads is - there is still more information needed to answer your question. For instance, what musical context (for example, solo or orchestra) is this tremolo or chord placed in? Or, as someone had previously mentioned, what is the instrumentation of the tremolo or chord? Such details need to be taken in consideration when answering this question, but there isn't enough at the moment.

Comment: Agreed, and you don't mention wether you intend this music to be played by people on real instruments either, the register where tremolo, and playing in general, becomes hard varies enormously for different instruments. On piano it's trivial anywhere, on some wind instruments it may be next to impossible in higher registers. On double bass for example it's quite possible but can be hard to 'sing' that high on the instrument, you'd also need a more experienced player for it to sound good. Lower down even a less experienced player shouldn't have too much problem.

Comment: I edited my question.